# MVC Core 2.0 Cookie authentication LoginPath option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use cookie based authentication in MVC 2.0 with localized URL. In "Configuration" function I'm using:

```
services.AddAuthentication("MyScheme")
            .AddCookie("MyScheme", options =>
                                   {
                                       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/Forbidden/";
                                       options.LoginPath = "/Auth/SignIn/";
                                   });
```

Everything would be fine, but I'm using localized URL like:

```
template: "{culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

Is it possible somehow to specify sime pattern in options above to suit the localization URL (like /en/Auth/SignIn/ or other languages)? Right now it is strongy set and this causes problems.

Thank you.

Comment: can you expand on the problems that are caused by the non-localized URL paths? Also, have you tried using route tokens in the AccessDeniedPath/LoginPath fields - e.g., `{culture}/Auth/Forbidden`?

Answer (score 2):

The `Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` has the `[PathString] LoginPath` and `[PathString] AccessDeniedPath` properties available to it, including the `Cookie` that is in the process of being constructed (CookieBuilder) and the `CookieManager`.

I'm not sure if it's absolutely necessary, but I feel fairly confident that you could attach a handler to one or more `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Events` that re-writes the cookie's path properties accordingly using the provided `RedirectContext` passed to the handler. [See ref - CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/23da47617624cfed065cd1cdd552d34e5ea5b821/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L411) to examine the details of how the path strings are used. In particular, you might look at the `CookieAuthenticationEvents:RedirectToAccessDenied` and `CookieAuthenticationEvents:RedirectToLogin`.

That said, I would first want to verify that you're not missing out on a way to get what you want via what's already built-in. Assuming your setup is something like

`services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))); });`

I would think that the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`would handle appending the culture to the `/Auth/Forbidden` URL that ends up being issued, hinting that there might be a more optimal solution somewhere in how the components are being configured rather than in custom rewriting of paths.

Some additional references:

https://andrewlock.net/url-culture-provider-using-middleware-as-mvc-filter-in-asp-net-core-1-1-0/

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/488eb44467eb677eab62bdc49aa6255cc1be3119/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs